# instascan scanner as promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'am using instascan.min.js to use my webcam in FF. All working. How can i detect that a qrcode is read en then continue a script? I think it has something to do with promise but i can't figure it out.

steps are.
1. start scanner and wait for user to scan qrcode
2. Catch qrcode and save to sessionStorage
3. call another function

this is the sample code i've used:

```
function startScanner() {
$('#preview').show();
let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({
    video: document.getElementById('preview'),
    continuous: true,
    mirror: false,
    captureImage: false,
    backgroundScan: true,
    refractoryPeriod: 1000,
    scanPeriod: 1
});
scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
   return content;
});

Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
    if (cameras.length > 0) {
        scanner.start(cameras[0]);
    } else {
        console.error('No cameras found.');
    }
}).catch(function (e) {
    alert('No camera found which can be used.')
    console.error(e);
});
}
```

i don't know how to catch the content var en make the script execute further.